# Not receiving any data back from bittorrent peer handshake

Tags: python, tcp, bittorrent, asyncore

I'm having some trouble on the bit torrent protocol. I'm at the point of sending a handshake message to some peers. I have my client basically connect to every peer in list then send the 'handshake'. Code is below -

```
peer_id = 'autobahn012345678bit'
peer_id = peer_id.encode('utf-8')
pstr = 'BitTorrent protocol'
pstr = pstr.encode('utf-8')
pstrlen = chr(19)
pstrlen = pstrlen.encode('utf-8')
reserved = chr(0) * 8
reserved = reserved.encode('utf-8')
```

There are my variables that I'm sending. My msg is -

```
msg = (pstrlen + pstr + reserved + new.torrent_hash() + peer_id)
```

Based on the bit torrent specification my message is the appropriate len of 49 + len(pstr) -

```
lenmsg = (pstrlen + reserved + new.torrent_hash() + peer_id)

print(lenmsg)
print(len(lenmsg))
```

is out put -

```
b'\x13\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94z\xb0\x12\xbd\x1b\xf1\x1fO\x1d)\xf8\xfa\x1e\xabs\xa8_\xe7\x93autobahn012345678bit'
49
```

the entire message looks like this -

```
b'\x13\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94z\xb0\x12\xbd\x1b\xf1\x1fO\x1d)\xf8\xfa\x1e\xabs\xa8_\xe7\x93autobahn012345678bit'
```

My main problem being I don't receive any data back. I have the `socket.settimeout(4)` and it'll just timeout?

Comment: Just to check, did you manage to solve this? my handshake message is also 68 bytes long, but i'm receiving an empty reply from the peer

Answer (score 1):

The output is incorrect, it misses 'BitTorrent protocol'.
A proper handshake string is 68 bytes long.

It should be:

```
\x13BitTorrent protocol\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94z\xb0\x12\xbd\x1b\xf1\x1fO\x1d)\xf8\xfa\x1e\xabs\xa8_\xe7\x93autobahn012345678bit
```

Comment: Okay I have that was a typo I do believe. If the message is correct then I can start looking as to why I'm not recv any handshake back from the peer. It could be that I'm not understanding asyncore?

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at the code. Maybe try to use WireShark and compare to a working client.