# creating a peer request for torrent

Tags: python, p2p, bittorrent, handshake, torrent

I have created a torrent tracker in python which returns the list of all seeding addresses and the ports on which they are seeding

I would like to create a handshake with them so I can start getting pieces and creating blocks (downloading the file)

so far, my handshake has been refused with the following error as the message I am sending to the peer is incorrect.

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

so far I have the following code for creating a handshake

```
 25 def genhand(t : torrent):
 26   temp = b'\x13'
 27   temp += b'BitTorrent protocol'
 28   temp += b'\x00'*8
 29   temp += torrent.info_hash
 30   temp += t.peer_id.encode('utf8')
 31   return temp
```

as a hexdump this is:

```
00000000: 13 42 69 74 54 6F 72 72  65 6E 74 20 70 72 6F 74  .BitTorrent prot
00000010: 6F 63 6F 6C 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 55 8C F1 4F  ocol........U..O
00000020: 80 A2 D0 BC A6 FB 90 8C  62 90 76 55 F1 84 A6 59  ........b.vU...Y
00000030: 2D 50 59 30 30 30 31 2D  38 38 39 34 31 38 30 32  -PY0001-88941802
00000040: 33 31 38 30                                       3180
```

the format for creating a handshake can be [found here](http://jonas.nitro.dk/bittorrent/bittorrent-rfc.html) under section 6.2.
as far as I can see, my format for the handshake is correct. what am I doing wrong?

thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985955/not-receiving-any-data-back-from-bittorrent-peer-handshake

related thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after playing around with this for a while, i discovered that my implementation was correct, but some peers are not kind in replying. after going through my list of peers for the torrent I discovered that some with reset my connection and some will reply with a a handshake

example:

```
sent
00000000: 13 42 69 74 54 6F 72 72  65 6E 74 20 70 72 6F 74  .BitTorrent prot
00000010: 6F 63 6F 6C 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 55 8C F1 4F  ocol........U..O
00000020: 80 A2 D0 BC A6 FB 90 8C  62 90 76 55 F1 84 A6 59  ........b.vU...Y
00000030: 2D 50 59 30 30 30 31 2D  30 35 30 36 30 34 34 34  -PY0001-05060444
00000040: 30 38 32 38                                       0828


back
00000000: 13 42 69 74 54 6F 72 72  65 6E 74 20 70 72 6F 74  .BitTorrent prot
00000010: 6F 63 6F 6C 00 00 00 00  00 18 00 05 55 8C F1 4F  ocol........U..O
00000020: 80 A2 D0 BC A6 FB 90 8C  62 90 76 55 F1 84 A6 59  ........b.vU...Y
00000030: 2D 46 57 36 37 33 46 2D  56 78 57 35 56 76 5F 30  -FW673F-VxW5Vv_0
00000040: 28 54 49 7E                                       (TI~
```

i am still working on getting a bitfield payload such as in this [article](http://markuseliasson.se/article/bittorrent-in-python/) so i can actually find which pieces they have